# I can't understand few lines of codes CS50 bottomup practice problem 4 week

Tags: c, cs50

I'm trying to understand the week 4 assignment (BOTTOMUP) but I'm totally lost. I understand that in order to "turn a photo upside down" you need to do the following basic steps:

1. Open the photo
2. Write them to the buffer
3. Overwrite the newly created file from the buffer
4. close old and new photo.

Everything is clear to me until:

```c
// Read infile's BITMAPFILEHEADER

BITMAPFILEHEADER bf;

fread(&bf, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, inptr);
```

`&bf` is a bufor? Can someone explain this in layman's terms?
I need to understand the basics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BITMAPFILEHEADER bf;`  declares a variable named `bf` that is a BITMAPFILEHEADER struct.

`&bf` takes the *address* of that variable to pass to the `fread` function. In other words, it's a pointer to your BITMAPFILEHEADER variable. That variable is the "buffer" (a section of computer memory) that the `fread` function will fill with the data from the file.

This code so far simply reads the header part of the bitmap file in that structure. The code that follows will use that information to figure out the size, pixel format, and layout of the image data that follows.

Since you question appears to be about basic C or C++ programming language concepts, I recommend you tag these kinds questions with tag for the programming language you're using. Also take a moment to format your code for Stack Overflow (see [How do I format my posts?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting))

Comment: Thank You Paul for respond. Ah ok so "BITMAPFILEHEADER" is the name of the struct and "bf" is a variable  that was created for this structure (through which we have access to the elements stored in this "BITMAPFILEHEADER" struct?) So can I write that bf is some kind of address to the struct?

Comment: Oh just found additional solution - >  So, fread(&bf, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, inptr); means read 1 time from the stream pointed by inptr the data of size sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) bytes and store it to memory address of the variable bf.

Comment: `bf` is the struct, and `&bf` is the _address_ of that struct (or, to use other terms, a pointer to the struct).

Comment: Since I've answered your question, please Accept my response by clicking the gray check mark next to my answer.